# jQuery .slideToggle jumping

Tags: jquery, button, slidetoggle, dropdown, sliding

my .slideToggle is bad. I don't know why.
Could someone help me?

```
.select-hidden {
  display: none;
  visibility: hidden;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
.select {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: $select-color;
  width: $select-width;
  height: $select-height;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dpkVRj

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the following from your `css`

```
.select {
  /*display: inline-block;*/
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Very helpful.